# Finding closed form for recursion to quickly compute the result

Tags: c++, recursion

Suppose we have the following algorithm:

```
    int com(int a, int b)
    {
        if (b==0 || a==b)
        {

            return(1);
        }
        else 
        {
            return(com(a-1,b) + com(a-1,b-1));
        }
    }
```

Are there methods to compute this result faster without using recursion?  I'm trying to optimize for speed, but this solution is much too slow.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 3):

The [usual formula](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) is

```
com(a,b) = a!/(b!(a-b)!)
```

where n! is n*(n-1)*...*3*2*1. For faster computation you can of course eliminate the factors that cancel each other out, so you are left with:

```
com(a,b) = a*(a-1)*...*(a-b)/(1*2*..*(a-b))
```

But for serious numerical computations you should use log-gamma function `lgamma` instead of rolling your own factorial function:

```
com(a,b) = exp(lgamma(a+1)-(lgamma(a-b+1)+lgamma(b+1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of them, particularly the multiplicative formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient